# SQL sales report by calendar week

Tags: mysql, sql, zen-cart

I've been Googling for a few hours... thought this would be easy, but clearly not for me :)

I've got sales data in two tables and I want to generate a weekly sales report for a specific item.  For this purpose, I don't care about dollar values, just number of units.  An a "week" is either a calendar week (whatever start day, I don't care) or just 7-day chunks back from current (so week 1 is the last 7 days, week 2 is 8 - 15 days ago, etc) - whichever is easier.  I'm simply trying to monitor sales trends over time.  Preferably it would span back over years so that if its the first week of January, for example, it wouldn't show just one record.

The data comes from ZenCart.  The relevant tables/column structure is here:

```
Table "orders" has columns: orders_id, date_purchased

Table "orders_products" has columns: orders_id, products_id, product_quantity
```

Where I'm having trouble is with the joins and syntax.

Comment: A lot of people use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to post data structure problems.

Comment: Can you please show us your tables with sample and expected data? :)

Comment: You know, I realize its a lot more simple of a structure than I thought.  Perhaps tables aren't really necessary.  I've edited the question.

Comment: The Zen Cart sales report mod has this feature built in, doesn't it? https://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for my needs:

```
SELECT o.date_purchased, CONCAT(YEAR(o.date_purchased), LPAD(WEEK(o.date_purchased), 2, '0')) as weekyear, op.products_id, SUM( op.products_quantity )
FROM orders_products op
LEFT JOIN orders o ON op.orders_id = o.orders_id
WHERE op.products_id = 331
GROUP BY weekyear
ORDER BY weekyear
```

Comment: +1 I've been away for a while. Great to see, that you figured it out by yourself. Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

If you have some `date/datetime/timestamp` column, you can use the [`week`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function in your where clause

```
select week(now()) as week, sum(units) as total
from sales
where week(sales_date) = week(now());
```

or the previous week

```
select week(now()) - 1 as week, sum(units) as total
from sales
where week(sales_date) = week(now()) - 1;
```

You must take care for the year wrap around from week 52/53 to week 0/1.

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63a89/4/1) for testing.

Comment: Thanks.  I need a bit more hand-holding than that.  I have no idea how to wrap around the week.  Also, I'd like it to show all the data in a result table... not one query per result.  Is that possible?  A "group by" kind of deal?

Answer (score 0):

In order to take care of the year end wrap. for instance, `week(12/30/2018)=52` and `week(12/31/2018)=52` both are considered week 52 of 2018. the first day of 2019 starts on a Tuesday. you can write a case statement as follows to move 12/30/2018 and 12/31/2018 to the first week of 2019. so that you will have a complete 7 days week to compare:

```
case when order_date in ( '2018-12-30', '2018-12-31')
     then 0
     else week(order_date)
end as order_week
```

Comment: I am new here. I have a very naive question. How do you properly formatted the sql code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help shows you how - use the question mark symbol on the right when you are editing a question.